# zsh completion of paths with a prefix

Tags: path, autocomplete, zsh

I'm trying to get `zsh` to [autocomplete](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#writing-completion-functions-using-_regex_arguments-and-_regex_words) a custom command.

The idea is that in my command `foo`:

```
foo --args @path/to/fi
```

all arguments with an "@" at the beginning should be autocompleted the same as regular files, keeping the "@".

So in the example above, when pressing `<TAB>` I would expect autocompletion to suggest `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` (or `@path/to/file1.txt`, `@path/to/file2.txt`), given these two files exist in the folder `path/to`, so I could autocomplete it to, for example:

```
foo --args @path/to/file1.txt
```

I've looked at the [tutorial](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#writing-completion-functions-using-_regex_arguments-and-_regex_words) and the [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html), but can't quite get to grips with the syntax...

I expect I need something in:

```
_foo() {
  # What to add here?
}

#compdef foo
```

Comment: The `-P` argument to compadd should do what you want (it's accepted by _files). Are these paths supposed to take the place of normal arguments (like "read this file for the actual arguments") or is this just the format the command wants its paths?

Comment: Thanks @yut23, `-P` indeed looks relevant. It's the second, `foo` interprets paths starting with an `@` in a certain way.